# C# ListView How to create ContextMenu programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contextmenu

I have this code behind :

```
private void InitializeListView()
    {
        //RAZ
        lv.Items.Clear();

        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        gridView.AllowsColumnReorder = true;

        GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("SN");
        gvc1.Header = "SN";

        GridViewColumn gvc2 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc2.DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("a1");
        gvc2.Header = "A1";
        gridView.Columns.Add(gvc2);

        GridViewColumn gvc3 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc3.DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("a2");
        gvc3.Header = "A2";
        gridView.Columns.Add(gvc3);

        for (int i = 0; i < lv.Count; i++)
        {
            this.lv.Items.Add(
                new dataToUse
                {
                    sn= tab[i][0],
                    a1= tab[i][1],
                    a2 = tab[i][2]
                });
        }

        this.lv.View = gridView;
    }
```

in order to generate dinamycally this :

```
<ListView  x:Name="lv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="360" Margin="305,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="607" SelectionMode="Extended"  >

        <ListView.View >
            <GridView  AllowsColumnReorder="true">
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sn}" >
                    <GridViewColumnHeader>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Asc"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Desc" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding a1}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu >
                                <MenuItem Header="Asc"  />
                                <MenuItem Header="Desc" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding a2}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu >
                                <MenuItem Header="Asc" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Desc"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

The problem is that when I generate the project, I cannot see the ContextMenu (and so the MenuItems)

I already use this kind of code in another project, but here, it doesn t work...
I guess the code behind is the last one wich is generated, so if you could explain me how to create a ContextMenu programatically. Could be good.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't see where you try to create the context menu in code.

Comment: That s why I ask you your help :) I dont know how to create it in code ^^, but in my other project, I only needed to create the context menu directly in the XAML file, but now it doesnt work !

Comment: Then you should change the problem statement in your question... it reads as if you are wondering why there is no context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for the `A2` column. The others follow the same approach.

```
// Remove:
//gvc3.Header = "A2";
// Replace by:
gvc3.Header = new GridViewColumnHeader()
{
    Content = "A2",
    ContextMenu = new ContextMenu()
    {
        Items =
        {
            new MenuItem() { Header="Asc"},
            new MenuItem() { Header="Desc"}
        }
    }
};
```

In order to implement the actual sorting with possibility to sort by multiple columns, the menu items could be created with the following helper functions:

```
private MenuItem CreateAscendingSortMenuItem(string prop)
{
    var result = new MenuItem() { Header = "Asc" };
    result.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        var toRemove = lv.Items.SortDescriptions.Where(x => x.PropertyName == prop).ToList();
        foreach (var item in toRemove)
        {
            lv.Items.SortDescriptions.Remove(item);
        }
        lv.Items.SortDescriptions.Insert(0, new SortDescription(prop, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    };
    return result;
}
private MenuItem CreateDescendingSortMenuItem(string prop)
{
    var result = new MenuItem() { Header = "Desc" };
    result.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        var toRemove = lv.Items.SortDescriptions.Where(x => x.PropertyName == prop).ToList();
        foreach (var item in toRemove)
        {
            lv.Items.SortDescriptions.Remove(item);
        }
        lv.Items.SortDescriptions.Insert(0, new SortDescription(prop, ListSortDirection.Descending));
    };
    return result;
}
```

Then just create the items using the helper function instead of calling the constructor directly.

```
gvc3.Header = new GridViewColumnHeader()
{
    Content = "A2",
    ContextMenu = new ContextMenu()
    {
        Items =
        {
            CreateAscendingSortMenuItem("a2"),
            CreateDescendingSortMenuItem("a2")
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice :D ! that worked perfectly, and so how to link an event to this MenuItem Click programmatically ? may be you know ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks grek40 !

In addtion to your answer (how to create an event for a MenuItem):

```
// Remove:
//gvc3.Header = "A2";
// Replace by:
MenuItem item1 = New MenuItem();
item1.Header = "Desc";

//Event
item1+= new RoutedEventHandler(this.someFunction_click);

gvc3.Header = new GridViewColumnHeader()
{
    Content = "A2",
ContextMenu = new ContextMenu()
{
    Items =
    {
        new MenuItem() { Header="Asc"},
        item1
    }
}
};

//Function launched by the event
private void someFunction_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Thank you guys for your help !!!